# How to find sharepoint site URL from IIS

Tags: url, iis, sharepoint-2007

One of my team members had installed Sharepoint-2007 foundation on our server and has now left the organization. Now I would like to know the share-point URL because one of the application needs it during its execution. I have looked through the IIS (inetmgr) and could see a couple of virtual-directories related to Sharepoint but I cannot figure out the Sharepoint-site URL. OS installed on that machine is Windows-7 and this Sharepoint-2007-foundation installation is also available on VM having Windows Server 2008. I am not really a techie person and not much acquainted with Sharepoint. How do I go about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In the server which hosts SharePoint. `Click Start -> SharePoint Central Administration`  (if not found search for the link. Its usually under SharePoint Server 2010 products). Then goto

```
Application management -> Manage Web Applications
```

You will see the list of sites and their URLs there.